# bootstrap with flexbox heights

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have been trying to get a layout where I have a column of 6, plus a column of 6 to the right with two vertical boxes in. I can achieve this no problem, but I'm struggling to get the heights of the two enclosed divs to stretch vertically using flexbox.

I'm using this example http://www.bootply.com/7UhIWMK808 and adapting. Here's what I have been working with. Any ideas?

(I have been trying a variety of flex-grow & flex-col on the second column - but nothing seems to have solved it as yet)

```
<div class="container"><h3></h3></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-flex row-flex-wrap">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="flex-col">
       <div class="flex-grow" style="background: grey;">
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
        totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
        dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omn eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae 
        dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omn

       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <div class="">
           <div class="" style="background: grey;">
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
            totam rem ape

           </div>
        </div>
      </div>

       <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <div class="">
           <div class="" style="background: grey;">
            Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, 
            totam rem ap

           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>





</div>

</div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->
<hr>
```

Comment: I've been through your demo. Sorry, I'm not getting the problem.

Comment: Hi, no problem - it's now ok - I'll post the code someone helped with up top. Thanks

Comment: Ok. You should post a complete answer, so that future visitors can benefit from this post. Otherwise, just delete the question.

Comment: Hi, took me a while to stick it in, but it should be up top now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the the issue solved

```
<style>
  .flex-container {
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
  }

  .flex-column {
    display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
flex-direction: column;

flex: 1;
  }

   .child {
flex: 1;
  }
 </style>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-column">
<div class="child">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-column">
<div class="child">
  lorem
</div>
<div class="child">
  lorem
</div>
   </div>
</div>
```